# WINAPI pointer not working / wrong syntax? (beginner question)

Tags: c++

i tried to hide a call in the import address table of my program, by following code:

```
BOOL (WINAPI * pVirtualProtect)(  [in]  LPVOID lpAddress, [in]  SIZE_T dwSize, [in]  DWORD  flNewProtect, [out] PDWORD lpflOldProtect);
```

and later

```
pVirtualProtect = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandler("kernel32.dll"), "VirtualProtect");
rv = pVirtualProtect(exec_mem, calc_len, PAGE_EXECUTE_READ, &oldprotect);
```

The errors:

```
1.cpp(14): error C2143: Syntaxerror: Needed ")" before "["
1.cpp(14): error C2065: "in": undeclared Identifier 
1.cpp(14): error C2057: Constant expression expected
1.cpp(14): error C2466: Assignment of the Arrays not possible with constant size 0.
1.cpp(14): error C2090: Functional result is an array
1.cpp(14): error C2054: After "pVirtualProtect" should follow "(" 
1.cpp(14): error C2085: "lpAddress": Not included in the formal parameter list
1.cpp(14): error C2059: Syntaxerror: "["
1.cpp(14): error C2059: Syntaxerror: ")"
```

What is the problem here? Im thankful for every answer.

Comment: By the way, just try `#include <memoryapi.h>` and then call `VirtualProtect` directly.  You shouldn't need to write so much boilerplate just to call a Windows API function.  But now that I read your question again, I guess you're doing this to try to obscure how your program works.

Answer (score 4):

You are not supposed to write `[in]` or `[out]` in your source code like that.  I suppose you copied that from some documentation somewhere, where it was used to indicate the purpose of those parameters, but your use of them in actual C++ code is invalid.

Comment: i first used it without [in] and [out] then these errors came: ``` 1.obj : error LNK2019: Reference to unresolved external symbol "GetModuleHandler" in function "main".
1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved external ```

Comment: In the future, adding invalid syntax to your program is never a good way to fix linker errors; it just makes you further away from having a working program.  The syntax checking happens before the linker runs.  Anyway, we try to keep questions small and focussed on this site.  Since I was able to help you fix the syntax error, please mark my answer as accepted.  Then you could ask another question about your linker errors.  Please include a [mcve] and all details about how you are compiling the code.

Comment: It should be `GetModuleHandle` not `GetModuleHandler` Related: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulehandlea

Comment: i figured out too, sorry for the time waste